# Difference between "Response.PermanentRedirect" and "Delete Verb in MVC"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When using "Response.PermanentRedirect"

It will return back Http Response Code 301 which means permanent redirection to diferent location. This may not be any value for end user using the browser but for search engines it will help the search engines not to index permanently redirected urls.

**Question** - Does `Delete Verb` in MVC perform the same function ?

---

**Post** a new entity as an addition to a URI. `Put` replaces an entity that is identified by a URI.

**Question** - When performing the insert/update, the information is being submitted in both cases. Does it means in case of Insert, `Post verb` should be used and in case of Update `Put verb` should be used ?

Answer (score 2):

*To answer your first question :*

From the RESTful API point of view DELETE must be used to remove a resource from its parent which is often a collection or store. Once a DELETE request has been processed for a given resource, the resource can no longer be found by clients. Therefore, any future attempt to retrieve the resource’s state representation, using either GET or HEAD, must result in a 404 (“Not Found”) status returned by the API.

The DELETE method has very specific semantics in HTTP, which must not be overloaded or stretched by a REST API’s design. Specifically, an API should not distort the intended meaning of DELETE by mapping it to a lesser action that leaves the resource, and its URI, available to clients.

**204 (“No Content”) should be used in response to a PUT, POST, or DELETE request**

Response.PermanentRedirect indicates that the REST API’s resource model has been significantly
redesigned and a new permanent URI has been assigned to the client’s requested resource.
The REST API should specify the new URI in the response’s **Location** header.

**301 (“Moved Permanently”) should be used to relocate resources**

*For the Post and Put :*

PUT must be used to add a new resource, with a URI specified by the client and must also be used to update or replace an already stored resource. PUT must be also used to update mutable resources while POST must be used to create a new resource in a collection.